# Duel question, why shoot when $P_1 (s)+P_2 (s)=1$

Tags: probability, game-theory

There are two duelists with one shot each, their probability to hit from a distance $x$ is given by two functions $P_1 (x)$, $P_2 (x)$ that are both continuously and strictly decreasing from $P(0)=1, P(L)=0$. They walk towards each other from $L$ to $0$, and are each free to shoot whenever.

Our payouts: hit is 1, both miss or both die is 0 and die is -1.

We can logically come to the conclusion that they will shoot simultaneously, but we're having trouble showing that they will shoot from a distance $s$ when $P_1 (s) + P_2 (s) = 1$. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Assuming P1 is the better player we believe that P1 will shoot when when his payout is maximized (forcing P2 to shoot), this occurs at $max(P_1 (s) - P_2 (s))$.

Comment: Interesting.  Why would the inferior shooter wait to allow the superior shooter to get to their preferred distance?  If that would be positive expectation for the superior shooter, then the inferior one would be better off shooting at distance $0$, and thereby guaranteeing a $0$ outcome.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: To be clear:  my argument, if correct, would show that if $P_1(x)>P_2(x)$ for all $x>0$ then shooter $2$ should just shoot immediately to guarantee a $0$ outcome.  Waiting at all leads to a negative expectation for the inferior shooter.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being clear. I've updated the question. Both duelists only have 1 shot each. Also, if player 2 gets hit and misses his own shot, he gets -1 while player 1 gets +1.

If player 2 shoots too early with low probability, player 1 can just wait until he has 100% chance to hit, and then shoot.

Comment: Ah, that's my error.  In a traditional duel you start next to each other and walk apart.    If one player shoots, must the other return fire or can they hold off?  If I see you preparing to shoot, I can either return fire or hold off on the theory that, if you miss, I am guaranteed a win when we reach $0$ distance.  No?

Comment: They can hold off if they want to, but it would make no sense for player 1 to shoot, if player 2 hasn't yet and won't at the same time. Because if player 1 waits a little while longer, his probability to hit will increase - this is how we can conclude that they will shoot simultaneously. What we don't understand is why they shoot at a distance $s$ when $P_1 (s) + P_2 (s) = 1$, why that particular distance?

Comment: I don't see anything special about that distance, but I am not persuaded that I understand the rules.  I agree that the superior player should never fire prematurely, but I don't understand why the inferior one should wait for his adversary to get into an optimal position.

Comment: I think of it like this with $P_{sup} (s) = 0.8$ and $P_{inf} (s) = 0.6$: If the inferior one does not shoot simultaneously, his expected payout will be $(1)*(1-P_{sup})+(-1)(P_{sup})=-0.6$. But if he also shoots, his expected payout is $(1)*(1-P_{sup})(P_{inf})+(-1)(P_{sup})(1-P{inf})=-0.2$.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not persuasive.  Suppose we're at a distance where you will hit me with probability $.8$ but I'll only hit you with probability $.1$ ... then, if I return fire my expectation is $.2\times .1-.8\times .9=-.7$ while if I don't return fire then my expectation is $.2 - .8=-.6$ so in that case I am better off praying that you miss.

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing the problem clearly.  I'll think about it over the day and write if I have any useful ideas.  I think it's an interesting question, though I'm not sure the rules are fully clear.

Comment: Hmm you're right. How about this explanation: They only have 1 shot each, so if the inferier shooter shoots too early, we can always argue that he didn't choose the most optimal strategy. Because the superior shooter hadn't taken a shot yet, which means that the inferior shooter could have waited another infinitesimal time unit and gained a bit more accuracy.

Comment: Ah, maybe.  Here's an interesting thing:  If I return fire, your expectation is $P_1(x)-P_2(x)$.  If I don't, your expectation is $2P_1(x)-1$.  These are equal when $P_1(x)-P_2(x)=2P_1(x)-1\implies P_1(x)+P_2(x)=1$.   So I think the trick is to show that equilibrium occurs when those two expectations coincide.

Comment: Oh wow, that's the answer I was looking for! If you put this as an answer I will give you the green tick, huge thanks! :)

Comment: Well, glad you like it, but I am not persuaded that this really does provide an equilibrium.  It seems likely, but I think further argument is required.  Anyway I'll post it and edit as I think of more.

Comment: Note: I've added enough to persuade myself that this is the true equilibrium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what happens if shooter $1$ decides to fire.  This gives shooter $2$ a choice.  Either he can return fire or he can wait. Of course, if he waits (and survives) he is guaranteed a payout of $1$ at distance $0$. If he returns fire then shooter $1's$ expected payout is $$(P_1(x))(1-P_2(x))-(1-P_1(x))(P_2(x))=P_1(x)-P_2(x)$$

If shooter $1$ holds off then shooter $1's$ expected payout is $$P_1(x)-(1-P_1(x))=2P_1(x)-1$$

If equilibrium occurs when these expectations coincide then we have $$P_1(x)-P_2(x)=2P_1(x)-1$$ which is equivalent to $$P_1(x)+P_2(x)=1$$

All that remains is to show that when the two expectations do not coincide, both players should wait.

Toward that end:   Consider the difference of the two expectations $$F(x)=P_1(x)-P_2(x)-(2P_1(x)-1)=1-P_1(x)-P_2(x)$$

Then $F(0)=1$ and $F(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

Case I:   $F(x)>0$.  Then if shooter $1$ fires, shooter $2$ should hold off so shooter $1's$ expectation is $2P_1(x)-1$. That function is strictly increasing so shooter $1$ should wait.

Case II: $F(x)<0$ Then, if shooter $1$ is holding off, shooter $2's$ expectation is $2P_2(x)-1$ which is increasing.  It follows that shooter $1's$ expectation must be decreasing in that region, so shooter $1$ should shoot when $F(x)=0$.